# Search algorithm optimization

Tags: java, search, optimization

The code "works", but I'm having problems with optimization.

Algorithms idea is count the number of ways you can navigate n × n grid starting from the top left corner, always moving one step to the left, right, up or down, visiting each square. For example, when n = 3, there are 8 possible paths.

For example the algorithm gets unbearably slow with p.count(7), any hints/tips?

```
public class Paths {  

 static int[][] grid;
 static int n,counter;

 public int count(int n) {
 grid = new int[n][n];
 counter = 0;  
 search(0,0,1,n);
 return counter;       
}

 void search(int y, int x, int k, int n) {

 if (y < 0 || x < 0 || y >= n || x >= n) return;
 if (grid[y][x] != 0) return;

 if (x-1 > 0 && x+1 < n && y == n && grid[y][x-1] == 0 && grid[y][x+1] == 0) return;
 else if (x-1 > 0 && x+1 < n && y == 0 && grid[y][x-1] == 0 && grid[y][x+1] == 0) return;
 else if (y-1 > 0 && y+1 < n && x == n && grid[y-1][x] == 0 && grid[y+1][x] == 0) return;
 else if (y-1 > 0 && y+1 < n && x == 0 && grid[y-1][x] == 0 && grid[y+1][x] == 0) return;
 else if (y==n && x==n && grid[y][x-1] == 0 && grid[y-1][x] == 0) return;
 else if (y==n && x==0 && grid[y-1][x] == 0 && grid[y][x+1] == 0) return;
 else if (y==0 && x==n && grid[y+1][x] == 0 && grid[y][x-1] == 0) return;

 if (k == n*n) {
 counter++;
 return;
    }

 grid[y][x] = k;
 search(y,x-1,k+1,n);
 search(y,x+1,k+1,n);
 search(y+1,x,k+1,n);
 search(y-1,x,k+1,n);
 grid[y][x] = 0;
}
 }
```

Output:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
 Paths p = new Paths();
 System.out.println(p.count(1)); // 1
 System.out.println(p.count(2)); // 2
 System.out.println(p.count(3)); // 8
 System.out.println(p.count(4)); // 52
}
 }
```

Comment: A) if this homework, a slow solution might be acceptable. B) if this would be for a real world problem, then you shouldn't look at a brute force solution to get to that number. I am pretty sure it can be computed mathematically... Meaning: there is probably a (complicated) function that computes the number of paths for any given n.

Comment: `if (... || y >= n || ...) return;` followed by `if (... && y == n && ...) return;`??? Since you already returned if `y == n`, that entire second statement is meaningless.

Comment: Goal is to solve p.count(7) in less than 10s, now it takes roughly 40-50s